# Understanding the basics on PHP and MySQL security

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, security

I have always avoided learning PHP and MySQL because of what I have read on the internet about PHP not being a secure language and because of the security risks with databases (SQL injections etc).

The main thing I want to understand is the type of damage usually caused by poor PHP/MySQL code. In other words, what are we putting in risk when poor code is written, the information in the database or the entire server?

I know this may be a complex topic but I just want a brief explanation of what information is usually affected when a database or a PHP script is compromised.

1. When a database is compromised, does this mean that the entire server could be at risk or just the database and its content?
2. When a PHP script is compromised, does this mean that the entire server could be at risk or just the script and any content related?
3. What is the most important thing to keep secured when creating a database, the connection to the database?

Sorry for such basic questions but I need to understand this before I move on.

Comment: This is far too broad. To address your questions, however, PHP is not any more insecure than any other language. All languages are insecure if misused. And when you write bad code, the entire server may be at risk, or it may just be the database, depending on the nature of the problems. Assume everything is at risk. You should spend some time reading through the [OWASP website](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: I think PHP has that reputation for being insecure because for some time, it did not support prepared statements (though this has also been fixed for a long time).  Even now though, I see tons of people writing code that does not make use of them, and their code is hugely vulnerable.

Comment: Security has nothing to do with the programming language.  It's the code you write that counts, plus a few other things.

Comment: _When a PHP script is compromised, does this mean that the entire server could be at risk_ - in general, if a PHP script is compromised, it grants a remote attacker the ability to run PHP as the web server user. This means they can read, write and delete files as that user as well. The database contents could be stolen, and spam relays installed, depending on who is attacking and why. Most automated attacks are for the purposes of installing botnets or spam relays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SQL injection... when data is concatenated directly into a command, there is the potential for the data to be confused as the command.  This is true with just about anything, but we see it a lot in the form of SQL injection attacks on web applications.  For instance:

```
$evil_user_input = '0; DELETE FROM someTable WHERE 1=1';
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM someOtherTable WHERE fieldA = ' . $evil_user_input);
```

In practice, you can only run one query at a time so you have to get crafty, but the point here is that without escaping for the use in SQL, what should be data can be ambiguous.  This goes beyond security.  Suppose you have a field where a user types a quote mark.  Now you have broken SQL and your code crashes.

> 1- When a database is compromised, does this mean that the entire server could be at risk or just the database and its content?
>
> 2- When a PHP script is compromised, does this mean that the entire server could be at risk or just the the script and any content related?

Now when a database is compromised, or when your script is compromised, it is impossible to generalize as to what the issue is.  It all depends on what the attack was.  You can't say for sure that anything is ever truly isolated as many attacks rely on many pieces.  When something happens, you need to use your logs and other evidence to figure out what happened, and then fix it.

> 3- What is the most important thing to keep secured when creating a database, the connection to the database?

Use prepared/parameterized statements correctly and you don't have to worry about SQL injection attacks.  The connection to the database server itself should be over secure tunnels.  Most database wire protocols are not secure themselves... they are built for speed.  If you're accessing data over localhost, there is no tunneling needed.

Comment: Between this and @halfer's comment answers my questions. Thanks a lot.